# Efficient way to update every Dynamodb item based on attribute

Tags: bash, shell, curl, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

We have a DynamoDB table with ~8,000 records in it and we need to make an update to each record. Each record is structured something like: `id: 1492357, appIds: [123232], info: "{stringified json}"` and what we are desiring to do is take the "appIds" array and insert it to the stringified json value of "info" such that if we parse the json the appIds attribute is now an attribute in the json.

We have an API that will do this for us by calling `myApi/:id/update` and have a shell script that will fetch the id for each record in the table from dynamo. We could just loop the array of ids and curl the api with each id, but this seems inefficient.

Is there a native way in Dynamo to do something like this (bypassing the api)? I'm also not very familiar with scripting or curl, if there is not a native way to do it, is there a more efficient way to loop our array of ids and call the api for each one? We don't care about the api response at all other than if it has a 200 response or not.

**Current Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

records=`aws dynamodb scan --table-name myTable --attributes-to-get '["id"]' | jq '.'`
count=$(jq '.Count' <<< "${records}")
ids=$(jq -r '.Items | .[] | {id: .id.S} | @base64' <<< "${records}")

echo ========== fetched $count records =========
for id in $ids; do
  _jq() {
    echo ${id} | base64 --decode | jq -r ${1}
  }
  userId=$(_jq '.id')
  url=$(curl myApi/${userId}/update)
  echo $userId :
done
```

Comment: Is there something in the documentation that suggests something like this is possible? Have you tried something?

Comment: I've seen batch writes but have not tried it and it seems to be limited with the number of records you can update in one call and with throttling.

All we have tried is using the cli to scan the table to get all ids and then curl the api with each id. It works but will take hours if we do the full table. Wondering if there is an efficient way to rapid fire the curl requests since we don't need to wait for the response?

Answer (score 0):

I have a bash script similar to yours. I´m able to read the records from dynamoDB using bash. Then  I have another python script that uploads the items inside the dynamodb database. What you can do is call your python script inside your for loop and send the relevant arguments to it.

Bash:

```html
for item in "${table_data[@]}"; do
  argument1=$(jq '.argument1' <<< "$item")
  argument2=$(jq '.argument2' <<< "$item")
  argument3=$(jq '.argument3' <<< "$item")
  key = $(jq '.key' <<< "$item")
  sortkey = $(jq '.sortkey' <<< "$item")

  python3 cli.py update-dynamo-table --key $key --sortkey $sortkey \
                        --argument1 $argument1 \
                        --argument2 $argument2 \
                        --argument3 $argument3  #  > /dev/null 2>&1 &  Uncomment no to see the outputs of the python command

  echo "DynamoDB item updated correclty"
```

Python:

```html
import click
import sys
import os
import boto3

## Connecting to aws profile, boto3, dynamoDB table
aws_profile = os.environ.get('AWS_PROFILE')
aws_region = os.environ.get('AWS_REGION')
click.echo(f"Using profile {aws_profile} and region {aws_region}" )
session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name=aws_profile)
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name=aws_region)
table = dynamodb.Table('Name-of-dynamodb-table')

@click.group()
    def updateCommand():
    pass

@updateCommand.command()
@click.option('--key',  help='Primary Key of item on dynamoDB.')
@click.option('--sortkey',  help='Sort key of item on dynamoDB.')
@click.option('--argument1',  help='Value of argument1 to update on dynamoDB.')
@click.option('--argument2',  help='Value of argument2 to update on dynamoDB.')
@click.option('--argument3',  help='Value of argument3 to update on dynamoDB.')
## Declaration of function to update a table in DynamoDB.
## This function checks that the table exists annd if exists it updates the corresponding attributes.
def update_dynamo_table(key, sortkey, argument1, argument2, argument3):
    """Update an entry in dynamoDB table"""
    
    ## Validate that the item to update is actually in your dynamodb table
    response = pii_non_pii_table.get_item(
            Key={
                'key' : key,
                'sortkey' : sortkey
            }
        )
                
    if 'Item' not in response:
        click.echo("Item with specified keys does not exist, create it instead.")
        return None

    ## Table update
    ## Update expression string formation
    updateExpression = "set "
    expressionAttributeValues = {}
    expressionAttributeNames = {}

    if argument1 is not None :
        updateExpression += '#argument1=:argument1,'
        expressionAttributeNames['#argument1'] = "argument1"
        expressionAttributeValues[':argument1'] = argument1
    
    if argument2 is not None :
        updateExpression += '#argument2=:argument2,'
        expressionAttributeNames['#argument2'] = "argument2"
        expressionAttributeValues[':argument2'] = argument2
    
    if argument3 is not None :
        updateExpression += '#argument3=:argument3,'
        expressionAttributeNames['#argument3'] = "argument3"
        expressionAttributeValues[':argument3'] = argument3

    updateExpression = updateExpression[:-1]

    click.echo(updateExpression)
    click.echo(expressionAttributeValues)

    response = table.update_item(
        Key={
            'key': key,
            'sortkey': sortkey 
        },
        UpdateExpression=updateExpression,
        ExpressionAttributeNames=expressionAttributeNames,
        ExpressionAttributeValues=expressionAttributeValues,
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
    )
    ## return response
    ## Output message.
    click.echo(f"Table UPDATED correctly.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    updateCommand()
```

Let me know if this helps!!